# Подключить скрипты и стили к странице созданной loopback node.js

Tags: node.js, jade

Не получается подключить скрипты и стили к странице созданной `loopback node.js`, страница находиться
В файле `server\server.js` подключил подключил  `jade` шаблонизатор:

```
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','jade');
```

В файле server\boot\root.js определил следующие endpoints

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Index' });
  });
  app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Admin' });
  });
```

Создал файл `server\views\index.jade` с содержащий:

```
h1=title
form(method="post" action="/Users/login")
  div
    label Логин
    input(type="text" name="name")
  div
    label email
    input(type="password" name="password")
  button Войти
script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")
script(src="scripts/script.js")
script(src="../client/scripts/scripts.js")
```

Положил в папку `client\scripts\scripts.js` файл `scripts.js` который хочу подключить на странице `server\views\index.jade`
Запускаю приложение `slc run` в браузере открываю `http://localhost:3000/`
Страница и все её содержимое отображается но не получается подключить скрипты

```
script(src="scripts/script.js")
script(src="../client/scripts/scripts.js")
```

Браузер просто не находит(https://monosnap.com/file/RtvEFtyv3twYhoTcKPFfm3fjLkGWFl). Два разных тега стрипт подключил в надежде что хотя бы какой-то подключиться
Вопрос как подключить скрипты и стили внутри шаблона который на лежит в папке client?